# Is it possible to mirror Android screen to PC over Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, external-display

I have to show something on my phone to a large group of people, so obviously they can't just huddle around and look at the screen. I need to display what's on the screen to a laptop. I can't use WiFi, I don't have mobile data, I don't want to be tethered to the laptop with a cord, so the only option is Bluetooth. Range isn't an issue since Bluetooth works up to 100 ft (probably not that much, but much more than my needs)

Is there any way to do this, preferably for free?

Edit: people keep telling me Bluetooth isn't fast enough. Would a Wi-Fi Hotspot work? I'm assuming it doesn't matter is it's 2G 3G or 4G since the only thing that matters is that the 2 devices can communicate with each other, not the Internet.

Comment: The puny *real-life* speed of BT might pose a problem...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used [Screen Stream Mirroring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial). It is the app suggested by adeen-s.

I then turned on mobile hotspot but left mobile data off (don't need to waste that). I connected my laptop to the hotspot. Then using the instructions in the app, I was able to mirror my screen, though at an awful quality and a 5-second input delay. It does what I need, more or less.

EDIT: Using command prompt, you can make a LAN from the PC that you can connect the Android device to and use the 2nd mirroring app I suggested. This solution is best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth isn't fast enough to be able to cast your screen on a laptop. It would be possible using WiFi, a USB cable, mobile data or a Chromecast which again uses WiFi.

Short answer: it's not possible using Bluetooth.

If you still need to do this, there are several options available using WiFi. Try [Screen Stream Mirroring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial) app.